# select odbc - read date from a column in excel

Tags: sql, vba, odbc

I would like is a where where I take the parameter data from a range

thank you

I have a query from excel to sql using odbc, this is my query `cmd.CommandText = "select CVE_ART,SUM (CANT)`, what I would like is a where where I take the parameter data from a range

thank you

Comment: Are you using ADO or DAO?

Comment: i  use ADO THANK YOU